# How to disable Junit5 Jupiter engine in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, junit5, disable, junit-jupiter

I am creating my own test engine for JUnit5.
I want to run tests from Eclipse, using this custom engine.

When running configurations of the type JUnit test, Eclipse unconditionally adds default JUnit5 **Jupiter** engine jar file to the class path. So, when I am run tests from Eclipse, both the **Jupiter** engine and my custom engine are discovered and used by Eclipse. As the result, Eclipse attempts to discover and execute every test twice, using both engines.

The problem is that the tests I am writing the custom engine for, cannot be executed with Jupiter, so the testing process is just aborted.

The question is: is it possible to either configure Eclipse to disable the default test engine, or configure JUnit5 engine discovering process to disable particular engines, or do it somehow programmatically from the custom engine code?

I know, I can design my own set of Java annotations for test markup, so the **Jupiter** engine will just discover no tests, but I am currently quite happy with existing JUnit5 annotations, and I want to find a more simple solution first.

Comment: I’d assume that Eclipse will honour the engines included/excluded in your Gradle or Maven configuration. Have you tried that?

Comment: The Jupiter engine JAR is *not* included in Maven configuration. Eclipse does not show it in project Maven dependencies, but adds to the classpath when it runs the tests. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I suggest you read https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html and configure your engine includes correctly to give Eclipse a chance to do the right thing.